# Host both PHP and ROR with Nginx

Tags: nginx

Is it possible to host both PHP and ROR on same server with Nginx. Like if I have a wordpress blod and a redmine, an I want to host these two apps on same server with Nginx. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible

I normally use [Phusion Passenger](http://www.modrails.com/install.html) (http://www.modrails.com/install.html) with PHP-FPM (check your distro for install information) I'm using the [Webtatic rpms on CentOS 5](http://www.webtatic.com/packages/php53/) (http://www.webtatic.com/packages/php53/).

You will need to build nginx manually, but the Phusion Passenger installer will help you. or you can use the passenger ins standalone mode and use the proxypass feature in nginx.

Comment: I do not want to compile Nginx from source. I did not see any standalone passenger module for Nginx like we have one for Apache. Thanks for the help...!!

Comment: There isn't, nginx doesn't work with standalone modules... you always need to rebuild from the source... but the passenger-install-nginx-module script is very easy to use...

Comment: Yes I have tried passenger-install-nginx-module and its pretty simple. But If you have Nginx installed from source then upgrade could be a pain.

Comment: if you are using ubuntu, on Phusion page there is a reference to a "BrightBox" APT. This might help you, but consider using a compiled version with your "Chef/Puppet/etc" deployment agent of choice as a alternative to upgrade installation.